# Devise Custom Registration doesn't require anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, registration

I'm trying to make a three page registration with devise. Every time I hit next without filling the fields I can continue normal. I need to stop the user and require the to fill the fields.

This is the information.html.erb It highlights the Email field but when i click next it goes to photo_path even with empty fields. This wasnt an issue in the default sign_up devise form.

```
  <h2>Sign up</h2>

  <%= simple_form_for(@user, url: create_user_registration_information_path) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
      <h3>Personal Details</h3>
      <br>
      <%= f.input :name, required: true %>
      <%= f.input :surname, required: true %>
      <%= f.input :birthday, required: true %>
      <%= f.input :phone, required: true %>

      <h3>Location Details</h3>
      <%= f.input :postal, required: true %>

      <h3>Account Details</h3>
      <%= f.input :area, required: true %>

      <%= f.input :email,
                  required: true,
                  autofocus: true,
                  input_html: { autocomplete: "email" } %>

      <%= f.input :password,
                  required: true,
                  hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length),
                  input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>

      <%= f.input :password_confirmation,
                  required: true,
                  input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, 'Next', onclick: "window.location.href = '#{new_user_registration_photo_path}'" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <hr>

  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

and this is the Registration controller.

```
  def information
    @user = User.new
  end

  def photo
    @user = User.new(session[:user_information])
  end

  def account_details
    @user = current_user || User.new
  end

  def create_information
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    resource.save
    if resource.persisted?
      redirect_to new_user_registration_photo_path
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      render :information
    end
  end


  def update_photo
    @user = User.new(session[:user_information])
    @user.assign_attributes(user_params)
    if @user.valid?(:photo)
      session[:user_photo] = @user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_account_details_path
    else
      render :photo
    end
  end

  def create_account_details
    self.resource = current_user || User.new
    resource.assign_attributes(account_details_params)

    if resource.save(context: :account_details)
      create_profile(resource) # Create profile for the user
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      redirect_to profile_path
    else
      render :account_details
    end
  end

  private

  def create_profile(user)
    # Create a new profile associated with the user
    Profile.create(user: user)
  end

  def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :birthday, :phone, :postal, :area, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end


  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
                                :address, :birthday, :surname, :photo, :interests,
                                :skillset, :language_skills)
  end

  def account_details_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:interests, :skillset, :language_skills)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like your issue lies with the following line of markup:

```
<%= f.button :submit, 'Next', onclick: "window.location.href = '#{new_user_registration_photo_path}'" %>
```

Specifically, the `onclick` event code you've written is going to automatically redirect to the path provided regardless of any form validations. I would recommend removing the onclick event code to make sure the form validations prevent the form submission.

Further, I would recommend taking a look at the following article for a quick overview of how you can achieve a multi-step registration flow using the Wicked wizard gem:

https://medium.com/@jwong_75854/multi-step-user-registration-fdbce13f5eec

If you have more questions about this, let me know.